# CentOS + Fastsocket vs Windows Server 2016

Tags: database, centos, server, windows-server, aerospike

I am thinking ahead into the future here and trying to plan a server project for a company I am working for.

Does anyone have any experience with https://github.com/fastos/fastsocket?
From what I understand its already integrated into the CentOS kernel? or does it still need a kernel switch?

Most of the people on my team are Windows programmers so working with VS2015 on Windows 10 is something that we would prefer, however CentOS + Fastsocket would potentially allow the server to have better performance and security (questionable).

I am kinda hoping that someone here has some idea on what kind of performance numbers we would be looking at?

Also we are planning to use ZeroMQ + Aerospike DB, the application is a mobile app with a large user base, the more concurrent connections on a single server the better.

Thanks all